# How to recover "/boot/efi" partition

Tags: boot, fedora, bootloader, efi

I'm using Fedora 25.

Last night I formatted `/boot/efi` partition(which is located in a separate partition `/dev/sda1` 500MB ) unintentionally!

After that I can't boot into Fedora!

How can I recover `/boot/efi` partition?

Answer (score 2):

https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall

**This should help you**

In a nutshell, run this in a Live CD or USB, and the program will regenerate /boot/efi and /boot/efi/grub to permit booting. Alternatively, you can run grub-install from a Live CD using this strip of code:

> sudo grub-install /dev/sda1 *(Or any other /dev location)*

Comment: This also fixes other EFI issues such as booting into grub's command line, booting to a wrong drive, boot partitions missing in the BIOS boot list or F10 boot list. I get these issues when I swap in new boot drives, make changes to partitions such as installing Windows, messing up Linux partitioning, deleting boot partitions.

Comment: Unfortunately, the EFI scheme is rather fragile and requires all actors to do the right thing.